# Вычисление минимума из тех значений которые нужно вычислить

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема, нужно написать программу по нахождению минимального значения из множества полученных чисел. Числа эти получаются следующим образом: Таблица "А" - первая строка(значения X,Y,Zb)... всего 19 строк, заголовок одинаковый(X,Y,Zb), а значения все разные. И таблица "Eleme", в которой больше 10000 значений и заголовок X,Y,Z.

Так вот... необходимо по формуле рассчитать корень для каждых строк таблицы "А" (т.е. сначала 1 строку, потом вторую...), и из множества значений полученных выбрать минимальное, и записать в файл напротив данных в таблице "А" в соответствующей строке(напротив X,Y,Zb...). Помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: Есть файл excel, который на примере объяснит, что нужно делать... головоломка.(

Comment: Вопрос заключается в том, как это сделать. Вот ссылка на excel файл, надо сделать точно с такими же расчетами в делфи... http://files.mail.ru/UE09I0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вапрос о нахождении минимума те в делфях есть такая функция

```
function MinValue(const Data: array of Double): Double;
```

в модуле math.